# Extending Array.prototype in Node.js, from a require'd file

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have the following saved in test.js.  It successfully extends Array in the browser, but it doesn't seem to work with node and require.  Can someone explain what's wrong here?

```
(function() {

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return console.log("Array.prototype.max");
};
return Array.max = function() {
  return console.log("Array.max");
};

}).call(this);
```

Then, from a terminal:

```
> My-MacBook-Pro: me$ node
> var test = require("./test")
> [1,2,3].max()
TypeError: Object 1,2,3 has no method 'max'
    at [object Context]:1:9
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:307:10)
    at ReadStream.onData (tty_posix.js:70:12)
> Array.max()
TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'max'
    at [object Context]:1:7
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:171:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:307:10)
    at ReadStream.onData (tty_posix.js:70:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried it outside of the REPL (i.e. running it in a file)?

Comment: think I found it, see my updated answer.

Comment: This example now works in Node 0.6.  It is confirmed not to work in 0.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every command in the REPL is executed via `vm.runInContext` with a shared context object. This object is created at REPL initialization by copying everything from the `global` object. Since the require'd module will only extend `Array.prototype` *after* it has been copied to the context object, the modified version is never exposed.

Or at least that's what I could deduce from [the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js). I know nothing about the inner workings of V8 :) And as you probably have found out by now, your example works fine outside the REPL.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a file which includes your extensions:

array.extensions.js

```
if(!Array.prototype.Last){
    Array.prototype.Last = function(){
        return this.slice(-1)[0];
    }
}

if(!Array.prototype.First){
    Array.prototype.First = function(){
        return this[0];
    }
}
```

then include this file to your startup file.

app.js:

```
require('{path}/array.extensions');
var express = require('express');
/* rest of your code */
```

referring this file once on startup is enough to use...