# Changing the main environment in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some of you may or may not (probably not) know about my [framework](https://github.com/tylermwashburn/Ally). It's name is Ally, and I absolutely love using it.

Lately I've been doing a little bit of stuff in Node.js. Today I decided I was going to use it as my HTTP server, so that I could do server-side JS (in a PHP kind of way).

To do this, I started a project I'm calling [Trailer](https://github.com/tylermwashburn/Trailer) . While working on it, I found myself needing one of Ally's functions, Object:deploy. What it does is pretty much this:

```
var a = { a: 'a' };
a.deploy({ b: 'b' });
a.a; // 'a'
a.b; // 'b'
```

So I loaded it in..

```
var Ally = require('./Ally.js');
```

..but when I tried using it, it said it was undefined.

After a bit of digging I discovered that Object:deploy is defined in the Ally.js file, but the changes it makes to the global constructors don't stay.

How do I make the changes to global variables in the Ally.js file apply to the global variables in the file that required it?

**Note:** Ally is linked to above if looking through the source could help, and Trailer is linked to in case anyone wants to use it when I get a usable version out.

Comment: I don't see where you're doing the a.deploy bit

Comment: In Trailer? I haven't committed yet because it doesn't work. If you're talking about in Ally it's defined at line 176.

Comment: in trailer. I wanted to see the line that was broken. checking in breaking builds is still fine, so long as they are commented. Go ahead and push it so we can see what the whole codeblock looks like.

Comment: I don't see why it matters. I'm just asking how to let changes inside the module trickle down into the main environment. If you really need me to I can, but Trailer doesn't even really matter to this. It just happened to be what I was working on when I realized this behavior. All the code will show you is that deploy is undefined.

Comment: because if you declare the variable and _then_ define the function on the global object, it won't show up on the defined variable. I'm curious if you're doing that. You seem to exhibit enough knowledge to prove that you're not. I just wanted to see the code to confirm that.

Comment: Have fun. I just pushed it out.

Comment: Ah, see, I didn't realize you were doing it in the console! Now we both know ;) ... specifying the work you're doing in the console is important, for reasons such as those given below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this discussion](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/771) relevant? The key points here seem to be:

1. `require` won't extend global objects if you're working in the shell
2. It also won't work when `NODE_MODULE_CONTEXTS = 1`, though this doesn't seem to be the default for a script.

So if you're trying to run this in an interactive shell, that might be the issue. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739740/extending-array-prototype-in-node-js-from-a-required-file).

Comment: Incredibly relevant! :D If I were to run it in a JS file, rather then the shell, the extensions should stick though?

Comment: Just checked. It works when running it from a file, just not from the command line.