# Can you extend the Array object with a node module, but without importing it in every file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Bit of an odd one I think, but is it possible to make a node module that could extend the Array object with functionality such as `Array.prototype.min() | last() | max()` etc. But without having to import the module in every single page that you want to use it in. 
It could be in javascript or typescript, but I'd prefer Typescript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952227/1913729

Comment: @blex Yeah that could work, however I was wondering If I could do it without using require anywhere. I am pretty sure it is possible without it being in a node module, but not sure about the node module.

Comment: I'm not sure about that _(but I don't know)_. That being said, your question is explicitely asking how to make a node module. If that's not what you want, I suggest you clarify your question? Because the answer linked above  covers  a 100% of what you ask in the title. It can be put in a node module and does not need to be imported in every file (only in your starting -main- file)